# An url is launched correctly through selenium IDE , but not through script

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

i am trying to launch a url which once loaded will prompt for username and password .

Problem is that when i am recording and running the test cases through selenium IDE , it works .
However when i am trying to launch the url through code , it turns grey and does not show any prompt for username and password

**Observation :**

when i opened the URL manually

```
url =http://10.131.14.245:30016/index.html
```

it automatically redirects itself in few seconds to

```
http://10.131.14.245:30016/index.html#/Login
```

and the prompt for username and password looks visible .

However during script execution , URL is not redirecting itself and it remains

```
url =http://10.131.14.245:30016/index.html
```

even if we add the value '#Login' through code , it does not work

I am using 
Python 2.7
Selenium 3.6
Firefox 52.4
geckodriver v.018

below is the error in geckodriver.log file

```
1507793622480   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.18.0
1507793622495   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:56485
1507793624523   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]
1507793626284   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 56493
1507793626626   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
JavaScript warning: http://10.131.14.245:30016/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js, line 1: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead
JavaScript error: http://10.131.14.245:30016/vendor/requirejs/require.js, line 165: Error: Load timeout for modules: angular,ocLazyLoad,angular-ui-router,angular-translate,angular-sanitize,angular-translate-loader-static-files,angular-translate-loader-partial,angular-css-injector
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
#timeout
1507793619059   addons.productaddons    WARN    Failed downloading via XHR, status: 0, reason: error
1507793619078   addons.productaddons    WARN    Failed downloading via XHR, status: 0, reason: error
[Child 12096] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-esr52-w64-000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 345
```

below is the error in python

```
D:\userdata\khchoudh\Desktop\POC\Selenium Robotframework\Firefox>python worked2.py
EE
======================================================================
ERROR: test_worked2 (__main__.Worked2)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "worked2.py", line 21, in test_worked2
    driver.find_element_by_name("username").clear()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 437, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 843, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [name="username"]
```

Python code

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time, re

class Worked2(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "http://10.131.14.245:30016/index.html"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_worked2(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "#/login")
        driver.find_element_by_name("username").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys("xxxx")
        driver.find_element_by_name("password").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("xxxx")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button").click()

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException as e: return False
        return True

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException as e: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

HTML of the site

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title ng-bind="title">OpenDayLight DLUX</title>

    <meta name="description" content="overview &amp; stats" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
var module = ['angular','ocLazyLoad','angular-ui-router','angular-translate', 'angular-sanitize', 'angular-translate-loader-static-files', 'angular-translate-loader-partial', 'angular-css-injector'];
var deps = ['common/config/env.module','app/testsetup/testsetup.module','app/core/core.module','app/designboard/designboard.module','app/testautomation/testautomation.module','common/login/login.module','common/authentification/auth.module','common/navigation/navigation.module','common/topbar/topbar.module','common/general/common.general.module','app/topology/topology.module','app/yangui/main','common/yangutils/yangutils.module','common/sigmatopology/sigmatopology.module','app/yangvisualizer/yangvisualizer.module','common/layout/layout.module'];
var e = ['oc.lazyLoad', 'ui.router', 'pascalprecht.translate', 'ngSanitize', 'angular.css.injector', 'app','app.testsetup','app.core','app.designboard','app.testautomation','app.common.login','app.common.auth','app.common.nav','app.common.topbar','app.common.general','app.topology','app.yangui','app.common.yangUtils','app.common.sigmatopology','app.yangvisualizer','app.common.layout'];
        // global variables

    </script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- compiled CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/ng-grid/ng-grid.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/select2-bootstrap-css/select2-bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/footable/css/footable.core.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/footable/css/footable.standalone.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/vis/dist/vis.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/ng-slider/dist/css/ng-slider.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/opendaylight-dlux-0.2.0.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/sb-admin.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" data-main="src/main.js" src="vendor/requirejs/require.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <!-- the font-awesome is different from the 'official' one -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="src/app/testsetup/testsetup-custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="src/app/designboard/designboard-custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="src/app/testautomation/testautomation-custom.css" />

    <!-- application CSS -->
  </head>

  <body class="skin-3">
  <div ui-view="mainContent"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Correct the url in driver.get(self.base_url + "/index.html#/login") as your base url of setup also have "/index.html#/login"

Comment: @thebadguy problem still remains the same

Comment: The issue might be the focus is not on popup as the login element are present on popup, can you share the html of the site ?

Comment: @thebadguy please see the edit

Answer (score 1):

The type of error you are observing seems to me arising from the mismatch between `Selenium`, `geckodriver` and `Firefox` versions.

As per the Release Notes **`Selenium v3.6.0`** should go well with **`geckodriver v.0.18.0`** (where as **`geckodriver v.0.19.0`** is recommended).

But `geckodriver v.0.18.0` Release Notes clearly mentions the following:

> [**`geckodriver now recommends Firefox 53 and greater
>   geckodriver compatible with Firefox 56 and greater`**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.18.0)

So upgrading your **`Firefox`** to **`v53+`** level will definitely solve your issue.

### Update:

Based on your comment you can change the locator for `username` field to either of the following:

1. **`css_selector`**

   ```
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name=username]")
   ```
2. **`xpath`**

   ```
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
   ```

Comment: i upgraded my firefox to 56 and i m still facing the same error ..updating my logs above

Comment: No they are same , i thought there could be some changes. so you can refer the old one as well

Comment: See first set you are seeing `NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [name="username"]` where as in second set you are seeing `WebDriverException: Message: quit`. What is your exact Question?

Comment: i removed the quit error to avoid confusion..my question is that through scripts website is not getting loaded completely as a result after some time test case fails with "unable to locat.. error " . i want my url to get loaded completely

Comment: Ok, but your IP is ClassA IP, so won't be able to see if the website have a page load issue and how to solve it.

Comment: i have added the HTML code of site..see if it can be of any help

Comment: Great, but I don't see any element matching `driver.find_element_by_name("username")` or `driver.find_element_by_name("password")` in the provided `HTML`

Comment: i used webdeveloper>pagesource option to give above HTML code. You are right there is no field like username, however when i press F12 and click on inspector to navigate to the username text box , this is what i see 
 <input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="login.username" placeholder="Username" name="username" autofocus="" type="text">

Comment: This does not works because page loaded through code is not loading the entire page (blank page i am seeing)..That is the main issue..however manually or through selenium IDE its getting loaded

Comment: How are you so sure `page loaded through code is not loading the entire page`? Can you remove the `ImplicitlyWait` just before invoking the `base_url` i.e. `self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)`

Comment: ..same result...i am sure because when i am doing F12 and searching the text "Username" i am not able to see any match on the page open by the webdriver.

Comment: @pankajmishra Can't say anything more without seeing the url

Comment: @DebanjanB..i added an Observation section in my code, see if you can provide some clue on that

Comment: From your Question update I will suggest don't try to open `http://10.131.14.245:30016/index.html#/Login`. Try to invoke the url as **`url =http://10.131.14.245:30016/index.html`**. Let the `JavaScript`/`AjaxCalls` redirect you to the actual `url` and do their `HTML DOM` related sync task.

Comment: Hmm, the last thing which comes to my mind is to 1)Uninstall your browser with `Revo Uninstaller` 2) Use `CCleaner` to wipe out all the rotten stuff from your system 3) Install fresh `Firefox 56.0`

Comment: According to [selenium blog](https://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2017/08/09/firefox-55-and-selenium-ide/), Firefox 55 onwards in not supported. Try it with chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your driver is trying to grab the username field after the first load, fails with an exception and shuts it down before the redirect. It needs to wait. You could try:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
...
def test_worked2(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get(base_url)
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'username'))).send_keys("xxx")
```

Answer (score 0):

i was able to resolve this issue by using Firefox profile, i don't know what difference it made, but it actually worked.

**Link to create Firefox profile**

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Creating_a_new_Firefox_profile_on_Windows

**Below is the code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:/Users/<user name>/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/abc3defghij2.ProfileName')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
driver.get("https://www.example.com/membersarea")
```